# Not able to navigate to desired folder on remote Linux machine, how do i do that using paramiko?

Tags: python, windows, ssh, paramiko

I am Using Python paramiko and
My website server has folder structure like this-

```
1]dir1
      --dirP
      --dirQ
2]dir2
      --dirA
          --file.sh
      --dirB
3]dir3
```

where i want to access file.sh from dirA inside dir2 folder

I tried this-

```
import paramiko
client.connect('mysite.com', username='something', password='something')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cd dir2')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
for line in stdout:
    print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
```

but i get output-

```
  ...dir1
  ...dir2
  ...dir3
```

expected output is-

```
...dirA
...dirB
```

and also suggest how can i execute file.sh too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.exec_command("cmd ...")` is just like the command `ssh user@host "cmd ..."` so

```
client.exec_command('cd dir2')
client.exec_command('ls')
```

are just like

```
ssh user@host 'cd dir2' # this would not affect the following `ls'
ssh user@host 'ls'
```

. So you need to do like this:

```
client.exec_command('cd dir2; ls')
```

which is just like

```
ssh user@host 'cd dir2; ls'
```

Comment: Yes but i dont know if there is any process to accept the answer @whjm

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use variables need to add + for example

```
client.exec_command('str(var1)+str(var2))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.