# SSH Paramiko command is not changing the directory in remote server

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to change the directory to /etc/init.d using SSH paramiko module and cd command. It is not changing the directory. It is at default directory 'root' after logged in to the server

```
def StopAll(path,IP,ROOT,PASSWD):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('%s'%IP, username='%s'%ROOT,password='%s'%PASSWD)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd /etc/init.d")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd")
    print stdout.read().strip()
```

Output : ./Installation.py conf/Input.conf

**/root**

Please tell me where is the problem in code .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate ssh connection and execution of program with Python's Paramiko](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086065/automate-ssh-connection-and-execution-of-program-with-pythons-paramiko)

Comment: It is not duplicate. In that question, it is prompting for user inputs, but here it is not doing the same task. It is not able to execute simple linux command.

Comment: agreed, but the point is that you are using SSH at a much lower level than you have to.

Comment: To execute any commands on remote server, I usually use paramiko module. I think it should work fine. some small thing I am missing in the code. Need help to resolve it

Comment: exactly what the OP of the linked question was saying :) at first

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897381/

Comment: When I check 'pwd', it should be /etc/init.d.  But I am getting output as /root

Comment: @whjm, It will work only if we want to execute the cd and pwd command in one line . after that If I give pwd again in next line, it is showing /root

Comment: @saimanoj -- yes, that's how `exec_command()` works.

Answer (score -1):

you need to grab the sftp object and call cd on that:

```
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(ssh)
```

then

```
sftp.cd(path)
```

to perform the cd remotely

Comment: Hi @Kyle Roux , here is the error I am getting changing it to ssh.cd(path)

`./Installation.py conf/Input.conf

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Installation.py", line 61, in <module>
    StopAll(Installed_Dir,IP3,USERNAME,PASSWORD)
  File "./Installation.py", line 33, in StopAll
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.cd("/etc/init.d")
AttributeError: 'SSHClient' object has no attribute 'cd'`

Comment: Oh, yea you need to grab the sftp object and call cd on that: `sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(ssh)` `sftp.cd(path)`