# python SSH paramiko problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

Can anyone help me?

I am writing a script which connects to the router using ssh then creates a folder. For example; from port10 to port20, by entering start and end number.

After that I create a file with text in these folders. I am importing text(commands) from txt file using dialog window.

Text is like this: echo labas11 > port-cfg or  echo labas12 >> port-cfg

My problem: It creates folders in the necessary places, but doesn't create files with text where I need them. It creates in root directory not in /tmp/port(number entered)

Any ideas?

```
import sys, os, paramiko, xlrd, re, tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import *
#importing commands from txt
def pattern():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    tat= tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root)
    global pat
    pat= tat.read()
    print '\n',pat,'\n'
    change()

#creating folders and adding file to them
def change():   
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(hostname='192.168.1.254', username='root', password='root')
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        print ("Connection Failed")
        #rep()
    print ('\n')
    i=int(raw_input('start from'))
    y=int(raw_input('End at'))
    while i != y+1:
        pptt='mkdir /tmp/port'+str(i)
        ttpp='cd /tmp/port'+str(i)
        stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(str(pptt))  #creates directory in /tmp/
        for line in stdout.readlines():
            print line.strip()
        stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(str(ttpp))  opens # /tmp/port(number)
        for line in stdout.readlines():
            print line.strip()
        stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(str(pat)) #have to create file with text(file name port-cfg) in /tmp/port(number) but creates in root directory
        for line in stdout.readlines():
            print line.strip()
        print i
        i=i+1
    print ('\n')
    port = raw_input('\nWhich config you want to see\n'
    ppt=('cat /tmp/port' +str(port)+'/port-cfg')
    stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(str(ppt))
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        print line.strip()
    ssh.close()
pattern()
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: it has to create file in /tmp/port(number) but creates in root directory

Comment: take a look at this question: [Not able to navigate to desired folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897381/)

Comment: Thank you it helped